# Apply background color to a row in excel using pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a simple test sheet and I want to give the title row a grey background color using pandas. After the change, save the result as a new file.

[image]

I tried to use the following code.

```
df_test = pd.read_excel(r'...\test.xlsx')
df_test = df_test.loc[1:1].style.apply('background-color: grey', axis = 1)
df_test.to_excel(r'...\test_1.xlsx', sheet_name='asdf', index = False)
```

But I only receive `AttributeError: 'background-color : grey' is not a valid function for 'DataFrame' object`. I already tried a few other variations of this to no avail.

Comment: @NicoCaldo I already saw this before posting but I struggled with applying the solution given there. I would still consider myself quite the beginner.

Comment: Can you explian more what not working?

Comment: Solution was wrongly reopened - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783783/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-excel-cells-rows-using-pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Styler.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html)

```
def bg_header(x):
    return "background-color: grey"
    
df.style.applymap_index(bg_header, axis=1).to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Note: you need `Pandas>=1.4.0`

[image]

Comment: Why you reopen question?

Comment: Why not post answer to dupe?

Comment: `applymap_index` a dupe?

Comment: no, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783783/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-excel-cells-rows-using-pandas

Comment: Why reopen question?

Comment: cells / rows are not headers, no? I don't understand how your link solves the OP problem.

Comment: do you check dupe?

Comment: It create green columns, exaclty what need OP. So why reopen question?

Comment: Because OP uses the Styler and not the Workbook (Openpyxl)!

Comment: @Corralien This is exactly what I was looking for, I wanted to avoid using something like OpenPyxl and solve this in Pandas only. However, I have a problem when trying to use it. I get the message `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'applymap_index'`

Comment: You need **`Pandas>=1.4.0`**. Use `pip install -U pandas` or `conda update pandas`.